# Integral over a surface in kinetic theory

Tags: integration, kinetic-theory

I am working with some kinetic theory. I have the distribution function $\Psi (\vec{r},\vec{p},t)$, Where $\vec{r}$ is the radius vector, $\vec{p}$ is the unit vector of orientation, and $t$ is the time.

According to an article I read,

$$
\int_{p} \nabla_p \cdot \left( \frac {d\vec{p}} {dt} \Psi \right) dp = 0
$$

where the integration is over the surface of unit sphere. 
I spent some time to figure out why is it true, but didn't find an answer.
Also there is an equation on $\Psi$:

$$
\frac {\partial \Psi} {\partial t}+ \nabla_p \cdot \left( \frac {d\vec{p}} {dt} \Psi \right) + \nabla_r \cdot \left( \frac {d\vec{r}} {dt} \Psi \right) = 0
$$

I really convienced, that you don't have to use it.

Does anyone have an idea how to derive the first equality?

I think, some integration by parts technique can be used to derive this equality.

Edit: After my investigation, I am sure, that some general Integration by parts formula must be applied to derive the above equality. I think, this is Stokes theorem.

Comment: Are you sure $\vec{p}$ is a unit vector of orientation? Typically one sees $\vec{p}$ as the *momentum* of the particle.

Comment: Also, it might be useful to link to the article where you read about the integral. Or at least the author, title & year.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about it. The article is "Instabilities, pattern formation, and mixing in active suspensions" by David Saintillan and Michael J. Shelley, PHYSICS OF FLUIDS 20, 123304 2008

Comment: Ah, this isn't kinetics of particles (where momentum would be used), you've got rods that are distributed in space (which is why it's the orientation & direction). I don't see this exact integral in the document, can you confirm which equation it is? (Closest I see is (27), but it's not the same)

Comment: Please include relevant information from the article rather than just a citation in the comments. Also, please show what approach you have tried, and ask a conceptual question. Just saying "I didn't find an answer" doesn't really give us much to go on.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is used to derive equation (10) from equation (1). Actually, I think (27) is a key formula to answer my question.I don't get is as well. Is this Stokes theorem?

Comment: Daniel, I included all relevant information.

Comment: Sorta cross-posted to math: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393498/integration-by-parts-with-surface-integrals